# Logic Apps - Get Email Infos from http request body with json

Tags: json, azure, http, outlook, azure-logic-apps

How can you determine the email data from a request body and integrate it into the Outlook function?

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get your question actually. Do you need to pass the JSON from the HTTP request to outlook email ? or you need to deserialize the JSON and integrate into the outlook email?

Comment: i need the JSON to integrate into the outlook email

Comment: so you need the response JSON from the HTTP request to pass into the outlook Email .. right ?

Comment: that's exactly what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily send the whole `Body` of the response from the Http request into the Body of the Email using outlook.

See below

[image]

**Select the body from the HTTP request and pass it to the email body (as a raw JSON)**

[image]

**The corresponding code will look like**

```
{
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "office365": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/....../Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                "connectionName": "office365",
                "id": "/subscriptions/......./Microsoft.Web/locations/southindia/managedApis/office365"
            }
        }
    },
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Send_an_email": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "@{triggerBody()}",
                        "Subject": "test",
                        "To": "abc@abc.com"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much